# Change text for multiple buttons in one operation

Tags: c#, user-interface, forms, button

I have a form which consist of many buttons (50+) and they all have the same name except for the suffix number. (`btn_0`, `btn_1`, `btn_3`, etc.)

I want to change the text of those buttons in one operation.

Is there a way of treating buttons like arrays?

```
btn_[i].Text = "something"?
```

Maybe execute a string?

```
"btn_{0}.Text=\"something\""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to access each button at a time to do this.

Do it in a loop like this

```
foreach(var btn in this.Controls)
{
    Button tmpbtn;
    try
    {
        tmpbtn = (Button) btn;
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException e)
    {
        //perform required exception handelling if any.
    }
    if(tmpbtn != null)
    {
       if(string.Compare(tmpbtn.Name,0,"btn_",0,4) == 0)
       {
            tmpbtn.Text = "Somthing"; //Place your text here
       }
    }
}
```

Have a look for the Overloaded [Compare method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7tax739.aspx) used.

Comment: I would cast the `btn` variable using `as`, to avoid an exception.

Comment: @Shimrod I don't think you mean "to avoid an exception", you mean to ensure that the "right" exception is thrown.

Comment: Nope, I really meant avoid.  If you cast using `as`, no exception will be thrown if the cast is not successful, and the result variable will be null (which is what Shekhar_Pro checks just after the cast).  With his current code, if `btn` is not a `Button`, an exception will be thrown, and the `for` loop will end (and probably the application will crash).

Comment: @Everyone ok guys cool the heat.. i have edited my code..Thanx for you suggestions

Answer (score 1):

if you know how many buttons there is you can make a loop. though it's not perfect and there might be a smarter way to do this but I can't see why I wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Don't know specifics but the pattern probably goes like this

```
for each(Control c in this.controls)
{
   if(c is Button) //Check the type
   {
       Button b = c as button;
       b.Text="new text";
    }
}
```

or use excel with its autofil and text concatenation abilities to do it as a block of text. eg

```
btn1.text="hi";
btn2.text="world";
...
```

Answer (score -1):

why not use jquery to rename all at once?

```
jQuery("form :button").attr('value','Saved!')
```

Comment: Yes I did, the question itself can easily be solved with my example, and if tags should limit alternative solutions to problems you would miss out of a lot of good stuff.

Comment: I think Shekhar meant you can't use jQuery in a winform environment, which makes your answer pointless in this precise case.