# JavaFX Change text for multiple buttons in one operation

Tags: java, javafx

I need to change the text of multiple buttons in runtime.
Just like this, [Change text for multiple buttons in one operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724347/change-text-for-multiple-buttons-in-one-operation), but in JavaFX.

Comment: Do you have all the buttons references in an Array or a List? Are all the buttons laid out in one single parent control? What "operation" are you referring to which is responsible for changing the text?

Comment: I realy dont need to change the text. I need to change the background color. The buttons are in a GridView, wish is on another GridViewn. The "operation" is a ColorPicker onAction event. I can change the color for one button but need to do that for 9x9 grid of buttons.

Comment: If you want to change the color, rather than the text, that can be done very simply using CSS. You should [edit] your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color (which is what you indicate in the comments you want to do), you can use CSS.

If you give your main `GridPane` an id of `grid`, then the following CSS will make all buttons in the grid (either direct descendants, or descendants of descendants, etc) have a base color of white (the background color, as well as the "hovered color" and the "pressed color" are derived from the base color):

```css
#grid {
    -sudoku-button-color: white ;
}

#grid .button {
    -fx-base: -sudoku-button-color ;
}
```

Now in a controller, all you need to do to switch colors is do:

```
grid.setStyle("-sudoku-button-color: ... ;");
```

passing in the new color in some accepted CSS format.

If you want to set the text for each button, you will need to iterate through the buttons and set each text in turn. If you place the buttons in an array, this gets easier. Note you can further avoid repetition by defining an FXML for a "block" in the sudoku grid and including nine such blocks in your main grid.

The following demonstrates all these techniques:

sudoku.css:

```css
#grid {
    -sudoku-button-color: white ;
    -fx-padding: 2 ;
}

.sudoku-block {
    -fx-padding: 2 ;
    -fx-border-color: black ;
}

#grid .button {
    -fx-base: -sudoku-button-color ;
    -fx-max-width: Infinity ;
    -fx-max-height: Infinity ;
}
```

SudokuBlock.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<GridPane styleClass="sudoku-block" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="BlockController">
    <Button fx:id="button0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Button fx:id="button1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Button fx:id="button2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
    <Button fx:id="button3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Button fx:id="button4" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Button fx:id="button5" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    <Button fx:id="button6" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <Button fx:id="button7" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <Button fx:id="button8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
</GridPane>
```

BlockController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class BlockController {

    @FXML
    private Button button0 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button1 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button2 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button3 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button4 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button5 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button6 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button7 ;
    @FXML
    private Button button8 ;

    private Button[][] buttons ;

    public void initialize() {
        buttons = new Button[][]{
                { button0, button1, button2 },
                { button3, button4, button5 },
                { button6, button7, button8 }
        };
        for (Button[] buttonRow : buttons) {
            for (Button button : buttonRow) {
                GridPane.setFillHeight(button, true);
                GridPane.setFillWidth(button, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setButtonText(int column, int row, String text) {
        buttons[column][row].setText(text);
    }
}
```

SudokuGrid.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>


<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SudokuController" >

    <top>
        <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPicker" onAction="#changeColor" />
    </top>

    <center>

        <GridPane fx:id="grid" id="grid">
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block2" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block3" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block4" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block5" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block6" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block7" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <fx:include source="SudokuBlock.fxml" fx:id="block8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        </GridPane>

    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

SudokuController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class SudokuController {


    @FXML
    private ColorPicker colorPicker ;
    @FXML
    private GridPane grid ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block0Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block1Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block2Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block3Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block4Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block5Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block6Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block7Controller ;
    @FXML
    private BlockController block8Controller ;

    private BlockController[][] blocks ;

    public void initialize() {
        blocks = new BlockController[][] {
            { block0Controller, block1Controller, block2Controller },
            { block3Controller, block4Controller, block5Controller },
            { block6Controller, block7Controller, block8Controller }            
        };

        for (int blockColumn = 0 ; blockColumn < 3 ; blockColumn++) {
            for (int blockRow = 0 ; blockRow < 3 ; blockRow++) {

                for (int columnInBlock = 0 ; columnInBlock < 3 ; columnInBlock++) {
                    for (int rowInBlock = 0 ; rowInBlock < 3 ; rowInBlock++) {

                        int column = blockColumn * 3 + columnInBlock ;
                        int row = blockRow * 3 + rowInBlock ;

                        String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", column, row);

                        blocks[blockColumn][blockRow].setButtonText(columnInBlock, rowInBlock, text);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void changeColor() {
        Color color = colorPicker.getValue();
        int r = (int) (255 * color.getRed());
        int g = (int) (255 * color.getGreen());
        int b = (int) (255 * color.getBlue());
        String formattedColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        grid.setStyle("-sudoku-button-color: "+formattedColor+";");


    }
}
```

and finally the application class, Sudoku.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sudoku extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SudokuGrid.fxml")));
        scene.getStylesheets().add("sudoku.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a very nice approach since as far as i understand it, this solves the problem of text,  colour and others since i have direct access to button properties. You are building an object (BlockController) witch  is an array of 9x9 buttons. Then you build an array 9x9 of BlockControllers . And this blocks[blockColumn][blockRow] is an individual button. Very,very nice. Thank you allot @James_D. This is more than i could ask for.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to iterate through the list of children of the GridPane and if they are an instance of Button, operate on them:

```
colorPicker.setOnAction(e -> {
   ObservableList<Node> children = gridPane.getChildren();
   for (Node child : children) {
       if (child instanceof Button) {
          // Do something
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked nice. Im new to Java, but somehow manage to implement that code.  But ... by importing the gridPane to Controler (@FXML GridPane gp), i've lost direct acces to the buttons. Every where i had bt00.setText("kldfjg") for example stopped working. Another problem is that i con change all the buttons in a GridPane, but there are 9 GridPane's inside another gridPane. To declare that in @FXML would be a nightmare just to set the buttons text. PS, its a sudoku grid and i want to highlight a hole square, line and column.

Comment: For such large no of nodes, I would normally not create them using FXML. I would create the bare minimum UI using FXML and the rest can be created dynamically via Java code. **P.S.** - *You shouldn't add a question unrelated to current one in the comment section. Instead, you should ask a new question* :)

Comment: well, but it has to be FXML. So, there's nothing i can do. I was hoping there ware a simple way but ... never mind.... About the question, didn't see the need for a new question. Of course your answer is correct. It worked. Thanks. I will just change it button by button.

Comment: school project ... not my rules :(

Comment: @JPedro Why does it "have to be FXML"?

Comment: @JPedro So are you changing the color, or the text? Are you "allowed" to use CSS?